# How to define documents order in envelope using REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

If I have 3 documents: doc1.doc, doc2.doc, doc3.doc, but within the DocuSign Sender View, and also more importantly in the DocuSign Signing Ceremony, I want to be able to define what order those three documents are displayed in, how do I achieve this. For example, I may want them to appear specifically in the following order:

doc2.doc,
doc3.doc
doc1.doc

I am using the REST API, and so I imagined there must be a way of me specifying when I create my envelope definition, which order the enclosed documents should appear in? I noticed that there is an 'Order' property on the document object - great, but assigning values such as "1", "2", "3" against the relevant docs seems to make no difference, so perhaps this 'Order' property against the document object is not for the purpose I've outlined above?

Also, just to confirm, I am not referring to the 'signing order', which I have working fine via the recipient routing property.

At present, the documents always appear within the sender view or signing ceremony in the order in which they appear within the envelope (the order in which I added them to the envelope, regardless of 'Order' or 'DocumentId' properties). Is that just how it works (so I need to put the documents in the envelope in the physical order in which I want them to appear)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you answered your own questions. Documents are added and shown in the order they're added in. Like a list or array (in some languages). You can change the order by removing and re-adding documents in the correct order.